# NSIS silent installer path overriding

Tags: path, nsis, silent

I'm running my program installer done with NSIS but the /D option seems not working (or better overridden inside).
Via command line I trigger:

```
installer.exe /S /D=C:\Users\Public\installDir
```

NSIS code is:

```
InstallDir "C:\Users\Public\${VERSIONSTR}"


Function xxxx
 ${If} $MultiUser.InstallMode == "AllUsers"      
 StrCpy $INSTDIR "C:\Users\Public\Dir1"
 ${EndIf}
 IfSilent 0 +20
   StrCpy $INSTDIR "C:\Userdata\Dir2"
FunctionEnd
```

The used installation folder is "C:\Users\Public\Dir2". Even if I comment the IfSilent block the installtion folder will be "C:\Users\Public\Dir1" but never the one passed via command line.
What's wrong in my script?

Comment: beware of your `IfSilent 0 +20`: it should be `+2`, not `+20`

Comment: are you sure that you pass in your function xxxx and / or that the `$INSTDIR` is not overridden later ?

Comment: Yes, I pass inside this function since the path is set accordingly to what it is written inside. I also not see somewhere is possible to overridde it but could be a my missing. What I have to look for?

Answer (score 2):

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
;InstallDir ; Do not use InstallDir at all so we can detect empty $InstDir
!define DEFDIR_MACHINE "$programfiles\foo"
!define DEFDIR_PERUSER "$localappdata\bar"
Function .onInit
${If} $InstDir == "" ; /D not used
    ${If} $MultiUser.InstallMode == "AllUsers"
        StrCpy $InstDir "${DEFDIR_MACHINE}"
    ${Else}
        StrCpy $InstDir "${DEFDIR_PERUSER}"
    ${EndIf}
    ${If} ${Silent}
        StrCpy $InstDir "c:\CrazySilentOverride"
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```